# RAKE with GENSIM

Tags: python, rake, information-retrieval, gensim, cosine-similarity

I am trying to calculate similarity. First of all i used RAKE library to extract the keywords from the crawled jobs. Then I put the keywords of every jobs into separate array and then combined all those arrays into documentArray.

> documentArray = ['Anger
> command,Assertiveness,Approachability,Adaptability,Authenticity,Aggressiveness,Analytical
> thinking,Molecular Biology,Molecular Biology,Molecular
> Biology,molecular biology,molecular biology,Master,English,Molecular
> Biology,,Islamabad,Islamabad District,Islamabad Capital
> Territory,Pakistan,,Rawalpindi,Rawalpindi,Punjab,Pakistan'"],
> ['competitive compensation,assay design,positive attitude,regular
> basis,motivate others,meetings related,improve state,travel on,phd
> degree,meeting abstracts,benefits package,daily basis,scientific
> papers,application notes']

---

> queryStr = 'In Vitro,Biochemistry,PCR,Western
> Blotting,Neuroscience,Molecular Biology,Cell
> biology,Immunohistochemistry,Microscopy,Animal
> Models,Presentations,Immunoprecipitation,Cell biology,Master's
> Degree,Bachelor's Degree,,,,,'

Then I wrote the following GENSIM code,

> class Gensim:
>
> ```
> def __init__(self):
>     print("Init")
>
> def calculateGensimSimilarity(self, texts, query):
>     dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
>     corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
>     lsi = models.LsiModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=2)
>     lda = models.LdaModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=2)
>     index_lsi = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(lsi[corpus])
>     index_lda = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(lda[corpus])
>     vec_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(query.lower().split())
>     vec_lsi = lsi[vec_bow]
>     vec_lda = lda[vec_bow]
>     print("LSI Model")
>     sims_lsi = index_lsi[vec_lsi]
>     print("LDA Model")
>     print(sims_lsi)
>     sims_lda = index_lda[vec_lda]
>     print(sims_lda)
> ```

It is printing LSA score 0 and LDA score 90%+ match. Kindly let me know where I am wrong and how can i modify to calculate the correct cosine similarity.

> LSA Score[ 0.  0.]
> LDA Score[ 0.94234258  0.9477495 ]